# Get prepared response from type orm query

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typeorm

I have a simple query where I need all the courses assigned to a user:

I have 2 Tables i.e `students` & `courses`

```
return await this.studentsRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('s')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('courses', 'c', 's.id = c.userId')
      .select([
        's.id',
        's.name',
        'c.id AS courseId',
        'c.title'
      ])
      .getMany();
}
```

So currently I am getting response like this from query above:

```
id  name  courseId  title   
1   user 1  11  course 1
1   user 1  22  course 2
2   user 2  33  course 3
3   user 3  44  course 4
```

But actually I want response like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "user 1",
    "courses": [
      {
        "courseId": 11,
        "title": "course 1",
      },
      {
        "courseId": 22,
        "title": "course 2",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "user 2",
    "courses": [
      {
        "courseId": 33,
        "title": "course 3",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "user 3",
    "courses": [
      {
        "courseId": 44,
        "title": "course 4",
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So how can I achieve such response?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be as simple as removing the select if you have defined the column correctly.

```
# students table
@ManyToMany(type => Courses)
@JoinTable()
courses!: Promise<Courses[]>;
```

```
return await this.studentsRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('students')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('students.courses', 'courses')
      .getMany();
}
```

https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/many-to-many-relations#loading-many-to-many-relations